# How can i sum the value in list with for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

i try to make multiple and then the result multiple will be the sum. but i got error in my code.

```
ds = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in ds:
    print(sum(ds[i]*i))
```

expected output

```
55
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ds = [1,2,3,4,5]
total = 0
for i in ds:
    total += i * i
print(total)
```

The output is `55`

Comment: how can i got 55 only

Comment: @uud I put the print statement outside the loop, that's why you only see 55. If you put it inside the loop, each iterables will show

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are wanting the sum of squares of the elements of `ds`, although your code is trying to index `ds` using one of its values (`i`), and is also trying to compute the sum inside the loop.

You can do it in one line using:

```
print(sum([i*i for i in ds]))
```

or

```
print(sum(i*i for i in ds))
```

(These two similar looking expressions do different things under the hood, although I'll skip a discussion of this for now.)

Or you could build up the sum e.g. by doing:

```
total = 0
for i in ds:
    total += i * i
print(total)
```

or use a combination of the two approaches:

```
squares = []
for i in ds:
    squares.append(i * i)
print(sum(squares))
```

Answer (score 1):

`for i in ds` iterates through the list.. so each `i` is an element of the list.

So `ds[i]` would certainly give you an error or answers you're not expecting.  I think what you want is the following:

```
s = 0
for i in range(len(ds)):
    s += ds[i] * (i + 1)
print(s)
```

Comment: This does not give the desired result of `55`. It doesn't even work at all.

Comment: Was just given the snippet of code, so without much context I just used the OP's code with modification and let the OP figure it out.

Comment: surely, i want to make the mean function in statistics.